# need to call force:createRecord from lightning component used in visual force page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-community

I am try to call lightning component from VF Page and trying to call force:createRecord from lightning component. but getting below error message:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Action failed: c:workLineItem$controller$doInit [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
>   Failing descriptor: {c:workLineItem$controller$doInit}

Below is code snipped

## VF Page

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:workLineItemApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:workLineItem",
          { label : "" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

## Lightning App

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
   <aura:dependency resource="c:workLineItem"/>
</aura:application>
```

## MarkUp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" access="global" >
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />    
</aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
({
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

       console.log("WorkLineItemController.doInit: Entered");

       var createNewRecord = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

       createNewRecord.setParams({
           'entityApiName': 'WorkOrderLineItem'
       });
    createNewRecord.fire();

       console.log("WorkLineItemController.doInit: Exit");

}
})
```

Comment: Is this is classic or lightning?

Comment: I am calling VF page from lightning related list button (List Button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`force:createRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) event is

> ... handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

Visualforce Lightning Out pages are not equivalent to the one.app container and do not support this and many other events.

If your core objective, as you mention in comments, is to prepopulate fields upon record creation, I would encourage you to try to execute this requirement using the purely declarative functionality available through Lightning Quick Actions of the Create Record type. You can add predefined field values, including static values and formula expressions, that will be populated whether or not you include the field on the Quick Action's layout. You can find examples on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_objectspecific).

If this does not provide enough flexibility, you can write a custom Lightning component and surface it as a Quick Action within Lightning Experience. The Visualforce page button is causing you to do a lot of unnecessary work and limiting your solution options.

Comment: Thanks David. Do you have any example of one.app container? also would i be able to call from List Button? because don't have option to call any other way.

Comment: The one.app container is, among other things, the Lightning Experience itself. You can use this event in a Lightning component that is presented directly in Lightning. You cannot use the event in a Lightning component in a Visualforce page.

Comment: probably i am not able to properly because i am new to this one.app. Let me clarify my requirement. I have to create new record with pre-populated values once i click on  button in lightning. I know, it's easy to do in classic with URL hack. not sure, if i am going in right direction or not (calling VF page then lightning component from VF page). Also i don't anything about one.app because i am new to saleforces. Do you have any other way to pre-populate field values when we open create new record window in lightning?

Comment: I've added some information in my answer.

Comment: Thanks David. Problem with Quick Action is that you can not place it on related list

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to instead use a lightning:recordEditForm to create the record. This is the component I use when embedding forms, or prepopulated forms in visualforce from lightning components.

You will however need to add more code to your markup and handle what happens once the record is created.